# Marks for name, marks in marksheet

Tags: python

I got this code, I understood everything but I can't understand this "marks for name, marks in marksheet",
What is meant by marks,for,name and marksheet, explain it briefly

```
marksheet = []
for i in range(0,int(input())):
    marksheet.append([raw_input(), float(input())])

second_highest = sorted(list(set([marks for name, marks 
in marksheet])))[1]
print('\n'.join([a for a,b in sorted(marksheet) if b == 
second_highest]))
```

Comment: Do you understand the next list comprehension `[a for a, b in sorted(marksheet) <...>]` which has roughly the same structure?

Answer (score 0):

Each element of your mark sheet is a list with two elements: a name and a mark. So by using `for name, mark in marksheet`, your code knows to reference the elements inside of your list.

Comment: Can't understand yet, could u make me easy

Answer (score -2):

```
second_highest = sorted(list(set([d for c, d in marksheet])))[1] #c: 'Berry' d: 37.21
```

It's a same way to run successfully.